# find -exec rm -r print delete

Tags: command-line, find

I am trying to delete terabytes worth of folders and would like to see that things are actually being deleted. Currently, the command

```
find . -name "labelled_point_clouds" -type "d" -exec rm -r {} +
```

doesn't show anything and I will be left waiting for days not knowing if it is doing something. How can I have the command also output each folder it deletes?

Comment: It's mandatory to use `-depth` in these situations, or `find` may feed objects to `-exec` that's already been deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your command is almost right. You should add the verbose flag to the rm command that you want to execute to see progress and paths removed.

```
find . -name "labelled_point_clouds" -type "d" -exec rm -r -v {} +
```

I added a directory structure similar to yours and put in a few files just for illustration.

```
find . -name "labelled_pointclouds" -type d -exec rm -r -v {} + 

removed './2/labelled_pointclouds/NARA-21-0006-0001_content.pdf'
removed directory './2/labelled_pointclouds'
removed './4/labelled_pointclouds/NARA-21-0006-0007_content.pdf'
removed './4/labelled_pointclouds/NARA-21-0006-0001_content.pdf'
removed directory './4/labelled_pointclouds'
removed './1/labelled_pointclouds/NARA-21-0006-0007_content.pdf'
removed directory './1/labelled_pointclouds'
removed './3/labelled_pointclouds/NARA-21-0006-0001_content.pdf'
removed directory './3/labelled_pointclouds'
removed directory './5/labelled_pointclouds'
```

So you can see the files removed and then the directory removed once it is empty.